# Slicing 2d array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

This is the Python code which I want to convert to Javascript!

```py
y[i] = x[i][:j] + x[i][j] + x[i][j + 1:]
```

I tried using the slice function but I cannot correctly implement it for a 2d array.

Comment: Give example inputs and expected outputs and your current attempt

Comment: For `python` arrays I'd recommend using `numpy`. What you're using are lists. If you want to use lists that's fine though. But year give example input and expected output, I don't know what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

So that's just some python fancy work for list comprehension but I believe you could accomplish such a thing with:

```
const x = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
];
var y = new Array(81);

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var row = new Array(20);
    for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        row.push(x[i].slice(j).concat(x[i][j]).concat(x[i].slice(0, j+1)))
    }
    y.push(row);
}

for(k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
    console.log(y[k]);
}
```

I'm not exceptionally good with javascript, but let me know if that helps.
-Or-
provide some more input/output so I can test with, any additional code, what you've tried or what you're expected output may look like.